# error al relacionar por clave foranea tablas

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un error al relacionar por clave foranea me genera la tabla pero no la relacion.
ya borre las tablas y las volvi a generar y nada
uso php artisan migrate

https://gyazo.com/7d8d84a46ba23775ca49a3a91833995d

```html
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('rude');

            $table->integer('peoples_id')->unsigned();
            
            $table->foreign('peoples_id')
            ->references('id')->on('peoples')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    
    
        public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('peoples', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('name', 150);
            $table->string('firstname', 75);
            $table->string('lastname', 75);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que veo es que aparentemente estás creando primero la tabla students antes que la tabla peoples, la cual intentas referenciar y por eso no la encuentra. A menos que el error sea otro (en caso que uses una versión muy vieja de MySQL por ejemplo), el orden de las migraciones que muestras debería ser algo así:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('peoples', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('name', 150);
        $table->string('firstname', 75);
        $table->string('lastname', 75);

        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('rude');

        $table->integer('peoples_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('peoples_id')
        ->references('id')->on('peoples')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: posiblemente fue el orden de las tablas borre las tablas varias veces en realidad no se como lo solucione pero quedo

Answer (score 1):

Yo me encontré con un problema parecido y la solución fue, crear las tablas y luego las relaciones.

Siempre que creo tablas con migraciones hago primero el Schema::create y luego un Schema::table con las relaciones.

Quedando la migración parecido a esto:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Todos los campos
    });

    Schema::create('peoples', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Todos los campos
    });

    Schema::table('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->foreign('peoples_id')
        ->references('id')->on('peoples')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    }
}
```